Insulating an attic in hot, dry weather
Have an attic on a single floor house, nothing up there but our AC and lines. We've been spending a fortune on electricity so I decided to try some insulation. It already has the insulation above the ceiling, I bought spray foam to try and block the heat out. It seems to have trapped it instead and it's much hotter than before, and I'm not sure if I just royally messed up and need to get rid of it or if I just need to invest in some exhaust fans.

What did you adhere the foam to? If you sprayed it directly on the underside of wooden roofing material, you have increased risk of rotting by trapping more moisture in the wood; there should be an air channel between the insulation and the roof.

None of us can tell from here with so few details and no pictures. Is the AC condenser in the space? Does it have acess to outside air?

More ventilation in an attic, whether natural (soffit & ridge vents), or powered (roof or cable fans) is almost always better.  You haven't said where you're located, but typical ceiling R-values should be around R-40, maybe R-48 nowadays.

Keshlam: That's exactly what I did, moisture wasn't something I considered since I live in an extremely dry area.
Ecnerwal: The condenser is up there, I added insulation into the spaces between the boards and protected the vents from any blockage. They're all untouched and have access to air. I'm thinking I will install some powered exhausts.

If you are already spending a fortune on electricity, adding another electrical load does not seem logical. Adequate soffits and some passive Chimney vents installed on the roof  should be your first consideration.

Your location would also help.
